# Writing to Label

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, console.writeline, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm currently trying to develop a web crawler in C# that will test the page exists, which is specified by the user. I'm hoping that once the crawler starts it will write the pages status to a windows form (which includes labels). But I'm having trouble getting the program to actually write to the form?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri fileURI = new Uri(URLbox.Text);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileURI);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        request.Method = "HEAD";
        bool exists = false;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            exists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

        }
        catch
        {
            exists = false;
        }
        finally
        {

            if (response != null)

                response.Close();
        }

    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write.ToString = ("Active");
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you want the label to be updated after button1 is clicked?

Comment: @TimFreese yes but if its possible to print text beside the label that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

All you really are missing is setting the label text at the end.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri fileURI = new Uri(URLbox.Text);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileURI);
    HttpWebResponse response = null;

    request.Method = "HEAD";
    bool exists = false;

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        exists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

    }
    catch
    {
        exists = false;
    }
    finally
    {

        if (response != null)

            response.Close();
    }

    if(exists)
    {
        label1.Text = "Active";
    }

}
```

Comment: Great stuff Tim thanks, its nipped that wee thing on the bud! the program is having trouble creating a web request based on the user input do you think that's down to me not parse the "fileURI"?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works!

```
 public URLTester1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    //Web Page Active?

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri fileURI = new Uri(URLbox1.Text);

        //tests http response 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileURI);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        request.Method = "HEAD";


        bool exists = false;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            exists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

        }
        catch
        {
            exists = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // close your response.
            if (response != null)

                response.Close();
        }

        if (exists)
        {
            label1.Text = "Active";
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Inactive";
        }
```